# OAuth2 Whats the point of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter rules since it has no priority over ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using OAuth2 for authorization and I don't find usage of the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` override  in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, since it's not executed at all, because ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter has priority over it.

The order of execution is: AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter -> ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter -> WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. It can manually be changed by `@Order` but it somehow breaks the tokens, so I would rather not to.

Let's say I comment everything in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter and then try to access `/api/topics`. In that case I'm going to get the following message:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

It means that the rules I have in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, are not executed at all, even tho I have `.antMatchers("/api/topics/**").permitAll()`. What's the point? What's the proper way of allowing `/api/**` and authorizing anything else?

By the way, I'm using `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure@2.2.6.RELEASE`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/topics/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token**", "/oauth/authorize**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${oauth.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${oauth.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${oauth.accessTokenValidity}")
    private int accessTokenValidity;

    @Value("${oauth.refreshTokenValidity}")
    private int refreshTokenValidity;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId)
                .secret(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValidity)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValidity);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you registring many SecurityFilterChain(Interceptors) by the configuration of AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer the priority of execution that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter had was lost in order to achieve everything working properly you have to set on your SecurityConfig:

```
    @Order(1)
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          //... custom code
    }
```

In ResourceServerConfiguration is very important to write `http.requestMatchers().antMatchers` rather than just `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers` cause this allow the filters can work properly each other, having ResourceServerConfiguration priority over SecurityConf respect to endpoints "/api/**"

```
    private static final String ANT_MATCHER_API = "/api/**";

    @Order(2)
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers(ANT_MATCHER_API).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(ANT_MATCHER_API).access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')").and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(ANT_MATCHER_API).access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
        //... custom code
    }
```

BTW the error: 
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}

is an error of the Oauth2 filter chain

Comment: Accepted your answer and anyone having same problem, you can also look at my answer, it's valid as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself. `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure` is supposed to have the configuration for authentication like login page, error page, etc. As for `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.configure`, it applies rules about to the REST API.

The reason that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was not working for me, is because WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter configurations are chained. Remember their order? Authentication Server -> Resource Server -> Web Security. In my case, I had `.anyRequest().authenticated()` in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.configure which basically authenticated all requests after that, so it couldn't reach WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter at all.

I also added `.antMatcher("/api/users**")` in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.configure to restrict that rule only to `/api/users`.

Here is the "broken code":

```java
// WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/topics/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token**", "/oauth/authorize**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

// ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Here is a working example:

```java
// WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth2/keys").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}

// ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .antMatcher("/api/users**") // that particular line applies the rule only for /api/users
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/users**").permitAll();
}
```